# Can't locate Arduino AT-Tiny

Tags: delphi, arduino, delphi-7

I have 2 types of ARDUINO-cards.  ATMEGA 2560 and ATMEGA 328P.

In my Delphi7 (XP64 sp2) I have modified the JvHidDeviceController Unit to show the PID/VID's of the abovementioned Cards. That works perfectly. And with the use of the TComPort unit I can communicate with the selected card. No problems here.

And here is the problem:

I connect my AVR MARK II (usb-tiny). System "says" OK.

(When I run the ARUINO program I have no problems communicating with the connected card.)

I run the Delphi program (JVHidDeviceController Unit), the 2560 and 328p PID/VID appear in a LIST-box but NOT the AVR-MARK II.

I Wonder why ?  Please help.

Comment: Maybe you let the USB device opened for exclusive access and then AVR-AMRK II cannot open it?

Comment: @fpiette :   Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know how open such a "device/ driver". I really do not know.   Any suggestions for links(s) ?   Thanks anyway.   KRIS

Comment: I use Arduino Nano and it is recognized as a COM port. The original Arduino has a FTDI serial communication chip which has a programmable memory. I program this memory to have a serial number that my Delphi application recognize to discover my "device" among others.

Comment: @fpiette:   There is a way to solve this problem.   I use one of my ARD UNO's as an ISP. The Arduino SOftware (IDE) has the software to turn a UNO into a ISP.   ANd the driver responses fine to JvHidDeviceController, and in addition I have the C software.And I can change the software to meet my needs. Thank giving me that idea. Kris.

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, you should either delete your question or better answer it so that others may benefit from your findings.

Comment: @fpiette:  Of Course. Very good idea. Herby done . Thanss for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

After a search on the WWW I discovered, that the UNO (328P) could be turned into a ISP programmer. And by doing so I solve 2 (sub-)problems.  I got the code ("bootloader")  and the UNO Stills responds to the JVHidDeviceController requests. (Final solution in reach.. ) Kris